# What does "Kiss something /Somebody goodbye" mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

1. You can kiss getting married goodbye.
2. When my boys hit 2nd grade and decided to ditch "Mommy"  for "Mom", it was really painful. U can't say kiss the kid goodbye anymore when you drop him off at school - at least not within view of his peers.

Answer (score 1):

This casual phrase colloquially means that you will never see the thing, person, or concept again.  Not ever.  Effectively, that thing, person, or concept is dead from your perspective.  Now, this colloquial meaning does not override the literal meaning within context-- it is perfectly valid for a wife to say that "She kissed her husband goodbye when he went to work" and in this context, it does not mean that she will never see her husband again.  But in all non-literal contexts, to kiss something goodbye is to lose it forever.

"You can kiss getting married goodbye" for example, means that you are telling the person that they will never get married, and would most commonly be said after a recent event, such as if they obtained a horrible disfiguring wound on their face which would discourage potential marriage suitors, or it might be said in the context of someone who refuses to change a negative personality trait ("If you don't quit being such a cruel person, you can kiss getting married goodbye!").